# HTMLAgilityPack node name filter doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I want to get the text of a page using `HTMLAgilityPack`.  I have some code for this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb TheWebLoader = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument TheDocument = TheWebLoader.Load(textBox1.Text);

List<string> TagsToRemove = new List<string>() { "script", "style", "link", "br", "hr" };

var Strings = (from n in TheDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf()
               where !TagsToRemove.Contains(n.Name.ToLower())
               select n.InnerText).ToList();

textBox2.Lines = Strings.ToArray();
```

The problem is, it returns the content of the `script` tag too.  I don't know why that happens.  Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that InnerText does not return what you expect.

In:

```
<A>
    Text1
    <B>Text2</B>
</A>
```

It returns:

```
Text1
Text2
```

Then, for example, for the root node, doing `document.DocumentNode.InnerText` will give you all the texts in `script`, etc...

I suggest you to remove all the tags you don't want:

```
foreach (HtmlNode nodeToRemove in (from descendant in TheDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                                   where TagsToRemove.Contains(descendant.Name)
                                   select descendant).ToList())
    nodeToRemove.Remove();
```

Then to get the list of the text elements:

```
List<string> Strings = (from descendant in TheDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<HtmlTextNode>()
                        select descendant.InnerText).ToList();
```